# phpMyAdmin is having a show plugins error on startup

Tags: mysql, plugins, phpmyadmin

My WAMP phpMyAdmin instance is now throwing a SHOW PLUGINS error on startup. It has never done this in the past, but now does this and will not start. Any ideas how to resolve this issue? I contacted support but haven't gotten a response back yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show plugins is introduced in mysql 5.1+. If you are using a newer version of phpmyadmin 3.x with an older version of mysql 5.0 then you will get this error. Solution would be to upgrade mysql or downgrade phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that for later versions, show plugins was deprecated. To fix the problem edit the following file:

`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE\modules\wb_admin_control.py` (windows)

or

`/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/PlugIns/wb_admin_control.py` (mac)

on line 588 comment out this line:

```
result = self.exec_query("show plugins")
```

so that it looks like this:

```
#result = self.exec_query("show plugins")
```

Then restart mysql workbench and everything will work as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL user might not have enough permissions to access the temporary folder